# Abs[Sin[4a]] not equal to 2Sin[2a]Abs[Cos[2a]] for a in $[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, trigonometry

I have a long expression which is not fully simplified because `Abs[Sin[4a]]` is considered different from `2 Sin[2 a] Abs[Cos[2 a]]` for $a \in [0,\pi/2]$ - which is actually not.

As a proof of that, if I run

```
Assuming[0 <= a <= π/2, Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a]] Sin[2 a] // Simplify]
```

I do not get `True`, but `Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a]] Sin[2 a]`. Of course, if I run

```
Assuming[0 <= a <= π/2, Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a] Sin[2 a]]  // Simplify]
```

I get `True`. Anyone has an idea why it is not correctly simplified? Anyone with the same issue?

I am using Mathematica 10.0 on a Windows 7 Home Premium machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was recently informed by Wolfram support, `Simplify` is not guaranteed to fully solve equalities or inequalities.  Take this example:

```
FullSimplify[Log[x] > 1, Element[x, Reals]] (* Log[x] > 1 *)
Reduce[Log[x] > 1, x, Reals] (* x > E *)
```

We can also get your equation to simplify by using `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a]] Sin[2 a] && 0 <= a <= Pi/2]
(* 0 <= a <= Pi/2 *)
```

As you can see, the equality has been simplified to `True`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the use of Reduce. However, I feel like using it for simplifications is in general more cumbersome, especially if you are working with expressions involving multiple variables/parameters and temporary assumptions.

Comment: @Nicola In fact it's even worse, since `Reduce` won't take arbitrary expressions, only systems of equalities and inequalities.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `ComplexExpand` to the transformations `FullSimplify` will try (since `a` is real).  But `FullSimplify` seeks to minimize the complexity of the expression, and the starting expression is a local minimum,  To get it over the hump, we can penalize `Abs`.

```
Assuming[0 <= a <= π/2,
 FullSimplify[Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a]] Sin[2 a],
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, ComplexExpand},
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 10 Count[#, _Abs, Infinity] &)]]
(*  True  *)
```

Perhaps the best way is to combine [2012campion's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21750/2012rcampion) method with this:

```
Assuming[0 <= a <= π/2,
 Simplify[Abs[Sin[4 a]] == 2 Abs[Cos[2 a]] Sin[2 a],
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. eq_Equal :> Simplify@Reduce[eq && $Assumptions] &}]]
(*  True  *)
```